# Variável altera valor sem motivo aparente em C

Tags: c, matriz, int

Estou escrevendo um código em C pra resolver o problema sugerido no post do Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/414761988665865/permalink/1390954547713266/
[image: Problema sugerido no Facebook]

Alguém pode me explicar porque alterou o valor das primeiras posições da matriz?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int teste; // Vatiável de teste
    int matriz[20][20];

    // Cria tabela 20x20 randômica
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matriz[a][b] = rand() % 99); // Cria um número randômico pra cada posição da matriz
            if ((a == 0) && (b == 0)) teste = matriz[0][0]; // Testando pq o valor da primeira posição (0,0) muda
            if (b == 19) printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n0,0 %d\n0,1 %d\n0,2 %d\n\n\nteste %d\n----\n",matriz[0][0],matriz[0][1],matriz[0][2],teste);

    int contH = 0, contV = 0, contD = 0, cont = 0, produto[396];
    for (int j = 0; j < 397; j++) produto[j] = 1; // Inicia variéveis do 0 ao 396

    // Verifica na horizontal
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++)
        {
            cont++;
            produto[contH] *= matriz[a][b];
            if (cont == 4)
            {
                cont = 0;
                contH++;
                b -= 3;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n0,0 %d\n0,1 %d\n0,2 %d\n\n\nteste %d\n----\n",matriz[0][0],matriz[0][1],matriz[0][2],teste);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Saída no terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta linha está errada

```
// for (int j = 0; j < 397; j++) produto[j] = 1; // Inicia variéveis do 0 ao 396 // *** erro
```

Deve ser assim:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 396; j++) produto[j] = 1; // Inicia variéveis do 0 ao 395
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso de 397 posições. Da maneira que vc disse só vou ter 396.

Comment: Você diz porque o último produto calculado só tem 3 números?

Comment: uai, então declare produto com 397 posições...você declarou com 386 posições

Comment: Na declaração da variável o 0 não conta? Se declarei produto[396], não seria 396 posições mais a posição 0?

Comment: Rapaz, se eu te falar que resolveu meu problema! Muito obrigado!

Comment: numa declaração o número que vem entre colchetes é o número de elementos do array, e nao o valor do último índice